# display object in html

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a query which returns this:

[image]

and in component I have this code:

```
pages: Page[];

constructor(private httpCall: HttpCall) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.httpCall.get('/pub/page/GetPageById')
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.pages = <Page[]>data
            console.log(data);
            console.log(this.pages);
        })
}
```

HttpCall is my service which works.

it logs this:

```
Object {Id: 6, Title: "asdasd", Content: "<p>asdasd</p>"}
Object {Id: 6, Title: "asdasd", Content: "<p>asdasd</p>"}
```

my page.ts class

```
export class Page {
    constructor(
        private Id: number,
        private Title: string,
        private Content: string
    ) { }
}
```

and in html when I write this:

```
 <h4 class="block-title">{{ pages.Title }}</h4>

 <div class="about-project">
     <p>{{ pages.Content }}</p>
 </div>
```

But instead of display my data it logs these errors:

> Error: Error in ./PageComponent class PageComponent - inline
>   template:5:40 caused by: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined ORIGINAL
>   STACKTRACE: zone.js:390Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in
>   ./PageComponent class PageComponent - inline template:5:40 caused by:
>   Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined..

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As you're getting data asynchronously your `pages` variable will be `undefined` at first.

You can use **elvis operator** to prevent that error:

```
<h4 class="block-title">{{ pages?.Title }}</h4>

<div class="about-project">
  <p>{{ pages?.Content }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `*ngIf` in your template. As you're getting data asynchronously.

```
<div *ngIf="pages"> 
  <h4 class="block-title">{{ pages.Title }}</h4>

  <div class="about-project">
    <p>{{ pages.Content }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```